# JMenuBar isn't showing up

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Does anyone of you have an idea why my JMenuBar `menuBar` isn't showing up?
I'm using a `JFrame` and a `JPanel`.

My class extends `JPanel` and has a `paint` method inherited (already with `super.paint(g)`).

I want to display some `JLabels` and `JTextFields` on my `JMenuBar` (I know that's not the purpose of it)

Here's my code:

```
public void createMenuBar(){

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBounds(0,0,1463,29);
    menuBar.setLayout(null);
    this.add(menuBar);

    ipLbl = new JLabel("IP-Adresse:");
    ipLbl.setBounds(5,2,150,25);
    ipLbl.setLabelFor(ip);
    menuBar.add(ipLbl);

    ip = new JTextField();
    ip.setBounds(150,2,100,25);
    menuBar.add(ip);
}
```

I'm calling this method after creating the JFrame, but right before doing `setVisible(true)`.

Look:

```
public IceHockey(){

    try {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e){}

    fenster = new JFrame("IceHockey");
    fenster.setSize(1479, 941);
    fenster.setLayout(null);
    fenster.addKeyListener(this);
    fenster.addMouseListener(this);
    fenster.setResizable(false);
    fenster.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    fenster.setContentPane(this);

    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);

    createMenuBar();

    fenster.setVisible(true);
    fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

Comment: **Don't use a null layout!!!**. This has already been suggested in one of your previous postings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751366/some-swing-components-not-showing-on-jframe. Pay attention to suggestions. We give them for a reason. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for a working example. The code will also show you how to better structure your class.

Comment: camickr I know, but this program is only for me and even my teacher at school told us, that we CAN use null layouts. So it's up to me what I'm using! Besides, the null layout is sooo simple to use!

Comment: `Besides, the null layout is sooo simple to use! ` - no it isn't. You have absolutely no idea how big a component should be to display properly. Hardcoding random numbers is a waste of time and will only cause problems in the future, especially when changes need to be made. Simple things like changing a Font will cause problems. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. Learn to use Swing properly! You haven't even learned the Swing basics yet (or you wouldn't be asking this question) so you have no idea what is or isn't easy. That only comes from experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the menubar to the frame with `fenster.setJMenuBar(menuBar);`

If you want to add the menu bar to the JPanel this post has an approach you can use:

[add JMenuBar to a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299846/add-jmenubar-to-a-jpanel)

Answer (score 1):

After creating the MenuBar, I think you still need to add it to your JFrame. Change createMenuBar() to return the JMenuBar instead of void, then you can write the following:

```
fenster.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
```

I'm unclear what the **this** is in your code for *createMenuBar()*, but I'm guessing it isn't *fenster* yet is something where adding is permitted.

Comment: "this" is the extended JPanel^^